# Attribute to display as a default after hiding the main one using CSS in Wordpress

Tags: html, css

In Wordpress plugin gallery "Everest Gallery" got some tabs which first display ALL pictures, and next according to the category assigned to a given photo. For example: ALL | GROUP 1 | GROUP 2.
Choosen tab is later displayed as "active" one.

What I need to get is to hide the tab responsible for **ALL**. Code of two tabs below when first is choosen as active and the second is inactive (there are two different classes in css):

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="eg-filter-trigger eg-active-filter" data-filter-key="all" data-layout-type="masonary">ALL</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter-key="h3MyESImhP" class="eg-filter-trigger" data-layout-type="masonary">GROUP 1</a></li>
```

I figure out that I can hide ALL group using below code in custom css section:

```
[data-filter-key="all"] {display: none;}
```

And it works! The problem is that on the first look, gallery still display all the pictures before I click on any other GROUP tab. How to make eg. GROUP 1 with `data-filter-key="h3MyESImhP"` display as a default?

I'm not programmer, so I hope that everything here is explained correctly and clearly for you.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a css question, there should be default setting in the Plugin. CSS has nothing to do with load data. You can only hide/show like the way you figured out.

If there is no config in the Plugin for that you have to change the php file in the Plugin, but after every update it will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, unfortunately there is no such option in the plugin. I will post an answer for my question with the php code of the plugin. Can you help me how to change it properly? The change will only be temporary, ultimately the page will be rebuilt completly soon, so I'm not afraid of overwriting the files after the update.